# Change Text File Encoding

Tags: c#, notepad++

How do you change a text files encoding through code?  I am using this code to actually create the file itself, but how can I change the encoding (change to UTF-8 w/o BOM)

```
string path = @"E:\Test\Example.txt";
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Create(path);
}
```

Comment: THe file does not have an encoding, the text you write into it has.

Comment: Is there a way to change the encoding of the text via code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like that, but I'm not sure this makes really sense, as it seems you have no content in your file...

If you have a content, replace `string.Empty` by the content

```
File.WriteAllText(path, string.Empty, Encoding.GetEncoding(<someEncodingCode>));
```

Edit :

```
File.WriteAllText(path, string.Empty, new UTF8Encoding(false));
```

Comment: Do you know the encodingCode for UTF8 w/o BOM?

Answer (score 1):

First, except in a few bases (eg. a Unicode BOM, XML's encoding rules) you will need some form of metadata to tell you the current encoding. While some tools will make a guess they are not reliable (eg. the various Latin encodings in [ISO/IEC 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) don't have anything to distinguish them).

Once you know the input encoding, pass an instance of [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a3kf7c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), created with the name of the encoding, to the [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor, create an instance of [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the desired output encoding and then pump strings from one to another.

(If you know the files are not too large: read everything in one go with [`File.ReadAllTetxt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and write with [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143376%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which take `Encoding` parameters.

Comment: The data was going to be manually cut/paste into the text file, just wanted it to be auto created. -- Which I now see that the text is what has the encoding, not the file, so your answer makes sense now.