# Is it possible to change files’ encoding azure blob storage using C#

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I use polybase to export file to storageAccount. But the encoding is UTF8. I need to change it to SJIS. is there any easy way to change it to SJIS using C#? is it possible to do it by using blobstorage’s rest api

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973023/change-text-file-encoding

Comment: if i use the way you told me, i think i have to download the file to local from blobstorage, change encoding and replace the file in blobstorage. right? the files’ sizes are a little big, so i don’t think it’s good.

Comment: You could deploy it as a C# console app job in Azure Batch, in the same data center. That would reduce the download time and dependency on local resources.

Answer (score 1):

For api, you can use [Set Blob Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-properties), then set `x-ms-blob-content-encoding` in the request header.

For code, if you're using azure blob storage sdk, you can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-container-properties-metadata#retrieve-container-properties). You should modify the code, since the sample for getting properties of container. You can use sample code for setting blob property as below:

```
  CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("xxx");
  CloudBlockBlob myblob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("xxx");

  myblob.Properties.ContentEncoding = "SJIS";
  myblob.SetProperties();
```

Comment: ContentEncoding has been set to "SJIS". Does it mean the file's encoding is SJIS? I download it, it's still UTF8

Comment: @Jeff_hu, I did a test at my side, and found that it actually cannot change the encoding inside the file :(. It's confused to provide this feature but seams do another thing. Maybe you should download it then change the encoding manually.